# Best Practices for event driven WPF UI update and Async Receive in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In an effort to learn c#, I'm writing an application that will continuously monitor UDP traffic on a particular port and update a WPF UI text block with received packet information. The following code works (UDP handler class instance `d` instantiated elsewhere in scope):

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (d.receiveClient)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var receivedResults = await d.receiveClient.ReceiveAsync();
                    byte[] buffer = receivedResults.Buffer;
                    Console.Write("Receiving Data: ");
                    Console.WriteLine(buffer[0].ToString());

                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
                    {
                        MyTextBlock.Text = "Rx Data: " + buffer[0].ToString();
                    }));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

While it works, it's certainly doesn't feel idiomatic or correct. I'd like to create a `Task<byte[]>` that contains the async receive logic in the class that currently contains `receiveClient`. Problem is it doesn't execute continuously; the task will execute once, then exit. I've tried restarting the task in `.ContinueWith()`, etc, and while the Task can be restarted, I seem to loose the hooks into the UI. What's the best way to accomplish an event driven, continuous receive that in turn updates WPF UI components in native c# (I'd rather not use WinPcap or its .Net equivalent)?

Comment: Since this is a subscribe/event situation, Reactive Extensions is going to be your best bet.

Comment: As the Task never finishes I would use a Thread instead of a Task. You could consider to use Messaging to send update notifications to the UI. Have a look for MVVM Light Messenger.

Comment: Downvoters -- I obviously don't know what I don't know.  I must be missing why this is a poor question. As written, the task never exits -- which is what I want. Encapsulating the same as a Task method on the class instance, it does. I want the posted behavior, but as a method. More importantly, despite my code currently working just fine, I want to learn how to do it correctly. A downvote without correction ensures I don't learn anything.

@unkreativ and Stephen Cleary, thanks for the direction. I will investigate both of your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to stick with an always running Task/Thread and passing messages back to the main application, I ultimately opted to use the `BeginReceive()` and `EndReceive()` methods with a custom event for handling data parsing. Essentially something like the following (distilled to essentials):

```
    public void Listen()
    {
        receiveClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ProcessIncoming), null);
    }

    private void ProcessIncoming(IAsyncResult res)
    {

         byte[] rec_bytes = receiveClient.EndReceive(res, ref rec_ep);
         receiveClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ProcessIncoming), null);

         PacketReceivedEventArgs args = new PacketReceivedEventArgs();
         args.IP = rec_ep.Address;
         args.Port = rec_ep.Port;
         args.Data = rec_bytes;
         OnPacketReceived(args);
    }

    protected virtual void OnPacketReceived(PacketReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<PacketReceivedEventArgs> handler = PacketReceived;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<PacketReceivedEventArgs> PacketReceived;

    public class PacketReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
         public byte[] Data { get; set; }
         public IPAddress IP { get; set; }
         public int Port { get; set; }
    }
```

In the main app, connecting, listening, and packet handling becomes (where d is an instance of the class implementing the above methods):

```
d.Connect(someIPString, portInt);
d.PacketReceived += _SomeHandler;
d.Listen();
```